# SceneKit: model pixelation with Blinn lighting model but not default

Tags: 3d, scenekit, augmented-reality, lighting, scnnode

This Wavefront model (https://poly.google.com/view/100p3RNw-5Q) becomes pixelated as illustrated by the screenshot when the model's materials are configured to use the Blinn lighting model. This does not occur with the default lighting model.

Is there some SceneKit setting that can alleviate this pixelation? The pixelation comes and goes as you rotate the model in front of the light.

**Code:**

```
let modelNode = scene.rootNode.childNodes.first! 

if let g = modelNode.geometry {
     // Loop over each face
     for m in g.materials {
         // Use Blinn lighting model
         m.lightingModel = .blinn
     }
}


fileprivate func addLightNodes(cameraNode: CameraNode) {
    // Create ambient light
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor(white: 0.75, alpha: 1.0)

    // Add ambient light to scene
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // Create directional light
    let directionalLight = SCNNode()
    directionalLight.light = SCNLight()
    directionalLight.light!.type = .directional
    directionalLight.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Zero
    directionalLight.light!.color = UIColor(white: 0.60, alpha: 1.0)

    // Add directional light to camera
    cameraNode.addLightToCamera(light: directionalLight)
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like pixel aliasing, it's looking more like z-fighting. Are there two surfaces sharing the same space, and competing over being shown?

Comment: @Confused there's only one node. You can download the model for yourself and use the code above to reproduce.

Comment: @Confused could you post as an answer please? this indeed was the problem, want to award you the points. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it really looks like triangles Z-fighting.
You can have one node only, but duplicated triangles in your model, so you'll have to check this in your DCC.